# how to add proper drop shadow in slidingmenu in RTL mode

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I want to add drop shadow effect to sliding menu(jeremyfeinstein) which opens from right side of the page.
and this is what happening to it

[image: wrong drop shadow my RTL layout]

but it should be something like following

[image: correct drop shadow sliding menu effect]

I have gone through sliding menu source and copied followings :

```
//in my activity
SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
//set the width to 10 and my padding to 10 in listview as well
sm.setShadowWidth(10);
//similar shadow effect inside original example
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#33000000"
        android:centerColor="#11000000"
        android:startColor="#00000000" />

</shape>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"

        />
```

but yet I got the wrong drop shadow effect how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found how to deal with the parameters of the component.

This is my solution :
Java

```
SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
sm.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu_xml);
sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
```

and other config you want

sliding_menu_xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >
...
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_shadow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

background_shadow.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#22000000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:startColor="#44000000" />

</shape>
```

And play with #00, #22, and #44 for color's effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have a More Easy Approach...

SLIDING_CONTENT will Slide (Excluding Action Bar)

SLIDING_WINDOW will Slide the Windows (Including Action Bar)

Try the Following Line of code on the attach of sliding menu

slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);